# How to use a two-dimensional C array of Objective-C objects?

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional C array of Objective-C objects. How do I access the members of those objects?

```
id array[5][5];
array[0][0] = [[Ball alloc] init];
```

The Ball class has two members:

```
int size;
CGPoint point;
```

How can I access size for the Ball object stored in array[0][0]? Please tell me how I can do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which runtime (32-bit or 64-bit) and whether you declare the instance variables (`size` and `point`) explicitly or have them synthesized by the runtime, you may be able to access them directly as in `array[0][0]->size`. *This is not a good idea* however. It will break on modern runtimes and is very much *not* the Objective-C way and breaks encapsulation by publicly exposing implementation details of the class.

In Objective-C 2.0, the correct practice is to declare a property for each attribute that you want to be puclically visible. Add the following to `Ball`'s `@interface` declaration:

```
@property (assign) int size;
@property (assign) CGPoint point;
```

And in the `@implementation` block of `Ball`:

```
@synthesize size;
@synthesize point;
```

You can now access size like `((Ball*)array[0][0]).size`. The cast is required for the compiler to recognize the dot notation as a property access. It is not required if you use the accessor methods (which are automatically generated by `@synthesize`): `[array[0][0] size]`.

Answer (score 2):

While it may not be completely relevant to your question (and maybe you're just using a simplified example), but why not use use structs instead of objects in this case? As both size and point are non-objects, it might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
@interface Moo : NSObject {
@public
    int age;
}
```

And then you can do this without warning:

```
Moo *m = [[Moo alloc] init];
m->age = 16;
Moo *arr[4];
arr[0] = m;
printf("Age: %d",arr[0]->age);
```

You could also do some casting:

```
id arr[4];
arr[0] = m;
printf("Age: %d",((Moo *)arr[0])->age);
```

This should work with any number of dimensions of arrays! 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Publicly exposing instance variables is NOT a good way to accomplish this in Objective-C. It makes for fragile code. I suggest Barry's solution above.

Comment: All he asked was how to do it.